# How can i get a my SQL count function to return 0?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, coalesce

I'm fairly new to SQL so excuse my ignorance or if I'm asking a basic question here. What I'm trying to do is get my table to return 0 values if an outlet didn't create an assignment in the last day. The code I'm using is this:

```
    SELECT public.outlets.title AS "Outlet",
           COUNT(public.outlets.id) AS "Assignment Count"
    FROM public.assignments 
    JOIN public.users
      ON public.users.id=public.assignments.creator_id
    LEFT JOIN public.outlets
      ON public.outlets.id = public.users.outlet_id
    WHERE public.outlets.dispatch_enabled = 'True' 
      AND DATE(public.assignments.created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP- interval '1 day') 
    GROUP BY public.outlets.title
    HAVING count(public.outlets.id) = 0
    ORDER BY public.outlets.title ASC
```

I've tried COALESCE but to be honest I don't really understand it well enough to know if I'm implementing it correctly. As it stands, the current code i'm using is giving me "NO ROWS RETURNED". I've tried taking various parts of my where clause out to see if that will help but nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` to `public.outlets` is defeated by your `WHERE` clause that checks values in `public.outlets`. It might as well be an inner join, which is why you're getting no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for Outlets with a count of Assignments? Because then I think you want outlets to be the "FROM" and a left join on assignments instead of the other way around.

```
   SELECT public.outlets.title AS "Outlet",
       COUNT(public.assignments.id) AS "Assignment Count"
FROM public.outlets
JOIN public.users
  ON public.outlets.id = public.users.outlet_id   
LEFT JOIN public.assignments
  ON public.users.id=public.assignments.creator_id
  AND DATE(public.assignments.created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-interval '1 day') 
WHERE public.outlets.dispatch_enabled = 'True' 
GROUP BY public.outlets.title
HAVING count(public.assignments.id) = 0
ORDER BY public.outlets.title ASC
```

Comment: this worked!! thank you! so to be clear, i was joining the tables backwards? again, sorry for my very basic question but thank you!!

Comment: Yup, start with the table you know will have a record and then left join to the table that might not have a record, then look for the rows that didn't have a record.    Not to confuse you but you also could have done this with a Left join is null format.  You can look up that and it would work almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the `left join` with the table where you want to keep all the rows.

```
SELECT o.title AS "Outlet", COUNT(*) AS "Assignment Count"
FROM public.outlets o LEFT JOIN
     public.users u
     ON o.id = u.outlet_id LEFT JOIN
     public.assignments a
     ON u.id = a.creator_id AND
        DATE(a.created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP- interval '1 day') 
WHERE o.dispatch_enabled = 'True' 
GROUP BY o.title
HAVING count(*) = 0
ORDER BY o.title ASC;
```

Note:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- You need to start with `public.outlets` because that defines the rows you want to keep (`SELECT o.title`).
- Other tables are brought in using `LEFT JOIN`.
- The condition on `assignments` needs to be in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.
- You can count the id, but `COUNT(*)` is simpler to type.

Answer (score 0):

You can move part of the WHERE condition to the LEFT JOIN, and I also think that you have to switch the order of the tables. Finally, you have to count a field on a table on the left part of the join, probably using distinct:

```
select
  public.outlets.title AS "Outlet",
  COUNT(DISTINCT public.assignments.id) AS "Assignment Count"
from
  public.outlets left join public.users
  ON public.outlets.id = public.users.outlet_id

  left join public.assignments
  ON (
    public.users.id=public.assignments.creator_id
    AND DATE(public.assignments.created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP- interval '1 day')
  )
where
  public.outlets.dispatch_enabled = 'True' 
group by
  public.outlets.title
having
  count(public.outlets.id) = 0
order by
  public.outlets.title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is in those lines

```
LEFT JOIN public.outlets
  ON public.outlets.id = public.users.outlet_id
WHERE public.outlets.dispatch_enabled = 'True'
```

It requires `public.outlets.dispatch_enabled` to be not null so effectively converting `LEFT JOIN public.outlets` to INNER. No row with `count(public.outlets.id) = 0` thus exists. Refactor it to

```
LEFT JOIN public.outlets
  ON public.outlets.id = public.users.outlet_id
     AND public.outlets.dispatch_enabled = 'True'
```